# C#/.NET Windows.Forms - what .NET functionality supports uploading and downloading multiple files at once?

Tags: .net, ftp

For a Windows.Forms application (C#), I have 2 functionality needs:

1. Upload multiple files at once (3 files, around 1mb each)
2. Transfer multiple files from server to client when ready

For #2, transfering from server to client, the solutions I am considering are:

1. Send from client to server
2. send a message to the client that the files are ready for download
3. Poll the server at intervals to find when files ready for download

Answer (score 1):

This is not clear - do you mean you want to both upload files from client to server, and also to download from server to client?

If the files are on the server, then solution 1) is simplest - send a request to the server to download the files, and have the server send them to the client. I don't see why this would take any time at all if the files are already on the server.

Answer (score 1):

I would use 3 `BackgroundWorker`'s to upload the 3 files simultaneously. After this upload succeeds, keep polling the server to see if the downloads are ready. When you find they are, use `BackgroundWorker`'s to download the 3 files simultaneously.

[How to: Use a Background Worker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221403%28VS.95%29.aspx)